# Centering a top element without making sides clickable

Tags: html, css

I can align the "Learn More" in the center for this responsive layout, but the sides are not clickable to the banner in the background. I outlined the paragraph tag in yellow. What can I do to keep Learn More in the center and to not use width:100% on it? What seems tricky is keeping it in the center for all responsive display resolutions, so a left-margin:45% isn't a good solution.

Uploaded a copy:
http://meowzen.com/pacific-wild.org/initiatives

[image: issue]

Comment: If it has a set width, try `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Remove `p` tag around button and gives the button a tag `display:block` and set `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wrapping paragraph, set the link width in css (`width: 90px;`) and make its `margin: 0px auto;` or you can play with the top and bottom margins as you wish.